# When/Why does Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() return a negative error code?

Tags: c#, winapi, interop

When calling a particular Win32 API function(From C# through Interop), it fails and returns a negative error code

Background:

I'm doing this on Windows 8 OS running inside a TAB.

Function Signature

```
[DllImport("dxva2.dll", EntryPoint = "GetMonitorCapabilities", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetMonitorCapabilities(
            IntPtr hMonitor, ref uint pdwMonitorCapabilities, ref uint pdwSupportedColorTemperatures);




Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
NativeMethods.GetMonitorCapabilities(hnd,ref x,ref y);
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

The above code reports

0
-1071241844

I thought the error code range was between 0 and 15999 according to 
 [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time if some function returns a negative error code it is actually an `uint` value. Casting -1071241844 to `uint` gives 3223725452 which is 0xC026258C in hex.

Searching for that hex error code in google results in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) showing that it is the error ERROR_GRAPHICS_INVALID_PHYSICAL_MONITOR_HANDLE.